# KiCad Gerber vs Layout Error

Tags: layout, kicad, footprint, gerber

When I look at a certain footprint on my PCB, either in the PCB document, the 3D viewer, or in the footprint editor, the pads all have clearance between each other. However, there is an overlap in the area surrounding the pads (I am unsure what this is called). See the picture below.

[image]

If I look at the pad in the 3D viewer, there is spacing between the pads as shown:

[image]

When I generate a Gerber file, the pads are shorted together as shown:

[image]

How can I resolve this issue, or make the area around the pad smaller so it doesn't overlap?

Generate the Gerber files of my PCB.

Comment: Which layer(s) on the gerber are shorted? Can you show a screenshot of the pad properties (especially the clearance settings) and the settings for the Gerber export?

Comment: The outlined area in the PCB editor is not part of any physical layer on the board. It's merely showing you the closest distance you can bring a trace without violating your clearance settings.

Comment: Something seems to be missing after *"...of my PCB"*.

Comment: The lines surounding the pads on the copper layer indicate the *pad clearance* (Maple' answer). There must not be any copper of a different net within those lines, but having them overlap is fine.

Answer (score 9):

There are several areas that surround (or encompassed by) the pads:
trace clearance (or just clearance), pad clearance, solder mask clearance, solder paste clearance, zone fill clearance, thermal clearance etc.

The pad clearance can be anywhere up to the entire distance between pads, so it often overlaps for very small components. It defines how close different nets can come to the pad and generally corresponds to the minimal *copper spacing* your PCB manufacturer can support. For example Elecrow allows down to 0.15 mm trace/pad spacing.

The mask clearance defines how close the solder mask comes to the pad, and in fact can be negative for mask-defined footprints. However minimal *mask width* is often larger than minimal copper spacing. In case of Elecrow it is 0.25 mm. This means that if the distance between pads is less than 0.25 mm the openings in the mask for nearby pads will overlap, creating one big opening for several pads.

Here, for example, the fragment of a layout with ISM330DLC sensor and two gerbers, one for copper and another for solder mask.

[image]

Most likely the gerber that you were looking at was in fact solder mask for such a small component. In this case there is nothing wrong with it and it doesn't need fixing. You can make clearance smaller for footprint or even individual pads, but it does not mean your manufacturing house will be able to manufacture it.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the wrong layer. What you show is the solder mask, not the copper layer. There are no shorts on the copper layer. That's all.